# open one workbook form another

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to open one workbook from another workbook programmatically, I have tried a lot of forums, but I have written this code with the help of your forum only .

```
Sub emptycell()
Dim strfilepath As String
strfilepath = "C:\Users\bchitlange\Desktop"

Dim strfilename As String
strfilename = "*final.xlsx"

Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\bchitlange\Desktop" & Dir$("C:\Users\bchitlange\Desktop" & "*final.xlsx"), ReadOnly:=True


End Sub
```

When my files are saved on desktop it gives me an error of cannot access desktop.

and when they are stored in drive it gives the following error -

`run time error 1004 application defined or object defined error`

Comment: You can't use the `Workbooks.Open` method to open multiple workbooks at once.

Comment: Sorry, I see what you are trying to do here now. You want to use `DIR()` to open the first file form a location.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to open the first file from the directory with "final.xlsx" use this:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\bchitlange\Desktop\*final.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True
```

Answer (score 0):

I did realized it later that  VBA will provide me the answer and hence I recorded the macro for that and this is what I got and it works fine

ChDir "C:\Users\bchitlange\Desktop\exp"
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\bchitlange\Desktop\exp\dest.xlsm"

Thanks